# Group by hour using Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I have a varchar5 column with times from

```
00:00
00:01
00:02
00:03

... all the way to 
23:59
```

How would I count how many minutes are in an hour? To get the result

```
00 60
01 60
02 60
and so on...
```

SQL:

```
select 24_HOUR_CLOCK
From time table
Group by ...
Order by 24_HOUR_CLOCK ASC
```

**Means to count records**

Comment: What is varchar5? Do you mean varchar2? Perhaps varchar2(5)?

Comment: What is 24_hour_clock? The name of the column in your input? Then if you GROUP BY (as you should), you can't have it in SELECT anymore, or in ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `substr` to extract first two characters from the time string and group on that.

```
select substr(col, 1, 2) hour, count(*) minutes
from your_table
group by substr(col, 1, 2)
order by hour
```

or find substr inside a subquery as @Mathguy suggested:

```
select hour,
    count(*) minutes
from (
    select substr(col, 1, 2) hour
    from your_table
    )
group by hour
order by hour
```

Comment: And perhaps also order by `substr(col, 1, 2)`. In general, the query engine will calculate such functions repeatedly (instead of recognizing that it's the same function and reusing the return value); for that reason, it may be better to compute the `substr` in a subquery, and then use that in SELECT, GROUP BY and ORDER BY in an outer query.

Comment: @mathguy - Updated. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @mathguy. It probably will not make a difference; the execution plan is the same for both queries.

Comment: @BobC -  Execution plans generally don't account for function calls, or do they?

Comment: @mathguy. You can see them in the Projection Information section. However if the execution plan is the same (ie same PHV), then I think it's fair to say that the function calls will be the same. There are some optimizations that are done in 12, to provide "late function calls" in some cases.

Comment: Thanks you for that quick answer. Does one of you guys have an email where I can ask more complicated questions?

Comment: @WinstHoward I would just try posting your questions here on StackOverflow. There are some smart guys and gals here. If you have complex question, I suspect the toughest part will just be explaining it :)